# how to get co-ordinate positions of all links on webpage in asp.net?

Tags: c#, html

my exact requirement is making a thumbnail and marking the links positions of webpage. The webpage urls will be passed dynamically. For this I need o get the link co-ordinates.
is any other way to do that?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can run a script on the page then jQuery offset should do what you need:

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

This method will find the offset of an element relative to the document.  You can then add your markers by adding elements with fixed position on the page.

However if you can't run scripts on the page and can only grab the HTML things could get pretty complicated.

I suppose you could grab the HTML, edit it dynamically to add the appropriate scripts using jquery, publish it on the web,  and use one of the many website thumbnail generators such as

http://www.shrinktheweb.com/

to grab a thumbnail of the page.

Comment: See my code is to read html WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("" + txtUrl.Text + "");
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream data = response.GetResponseStream(); using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
        {
            html = sr.ReadToEnd();

Comment: after wards i am collecting links html = ReplaceUrlStrings(html, getUrl1);
            string[] strarray = html.Split(new string[] { "</a>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); now how do you want to add that jquery code and find the link coordinates.please help

Comment: It would be better to paste your code into your question as a code block so it is readable.  I can kind of see you're trying to grab the HTML which looks fine.  I would then not be trying to find the links in the HTML itself but rather append a jquery script which made the necessary modifications when run in the browser.  The entire solution here is going to be pretty complicated so I can't really help with writing the code out line by line,  all I can really offer is the above high level overview of how it might be possible.

Comment: sorry,i have tried to paste whole code.But unfortunately the editing section kept displaying code blocks are not properly described.So i could not post the entire code.If you provide any emailid so that i can mail you.